# sql server how to use param with xml query?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I have this code working

```
UPDATE UserData
SET Data.modify('delete(/UsersData/UserXml[@user_id=23445])[1]')            
WHERE Id = 11;
```

But when I try this code it throw ex

```
declare @myXmlQuery nvarchar(120)
set @myXmlQuery = '/UsersData/UserXml[@user_id=23445]'

UPDATE UserData
SET Data.modify('delete(sql:variable("@myXmlQuery"))[1]')
WHERE Id = 11;
```

I get this ex :

> Msg 2264, Level 16, State 1, Line 11   XQuery
>   [UserData.Data.modify()]: Only non-document nodes may be deleted,
>   found 'xs:string'

Any ideas ?

thanks.

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server are you using? The ability to use `sql:variable` in most places was introduced in SQL Server **2008** - it's not available in the **2005** versions....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hacky way would be:

```sql
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @myXmlQuery nvarchar(120);

set @myXmlQuery = N'/UsersData/UserXml[@user_id=23445]'

SET @sql = N'UPDATE UserData
SET Data.modify(''delete(' + @myXmlQuery + ')[1]'')
WHERE Id = 11;';

PRINT @sql;

-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

I'm sure the XML gurus will swing around with a more practical answer. I'm more of a relational guy. :-)